# How to delete/redirect warning from error stream in powershell

Tags: powershell, npm

I am trying to make a build in tfs, but when the script encounters a warning it seems to send the warning to the error stream. I have tried to remove the last error in $error but that is not working. I have read in others resources, that mention that warnings are sent to stderr and are then seen as errors. Anyone else with a similar problem?

This is the error I am getting.
 ##error Warning: Ignoring extra certs from `C:\BldAgntTools\tfs-cert.crt`, load failed: error:0B07C065:x509 certificate routines:X509_STORE_add_cert:cert already in hash table

From what I read, warnings also go to stderr. So one idea would be to remove the last error from stderr.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to see happen when the error occurs? I can't tell if you want to ignore it, or if it's being hidden and you want to see it.

Comment: I want to see the warning. The problem is that it shows the warning as an error and doesn't allow to finish the build.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful if you can provide one with sensitive info redacted. It might be that message isn't actually from the Warning stream, but the Error stream with just the text "Warning".

Comment: I don't have much more to show. For some reason when it tries to build it throws this error. ##[error](node:12172) Warning: Ignoring extra certs from `C:\BldAgntTools\tfs-cert.crt`, load failed: error:0B07C065:x509 certificate routines:X509_STORE_add_cert:cert already in hash table and in the end ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream. I don't understand why a warning is seen as an error and is sent to the error stream.

Comment: Update: I sent the content of warning and error streams to output. When I did this, the build was successful. I then sent only the content of the warning stream and the build failed. So there is an error present, I don't understand how I can send the error stream to output with 2>&1 but not access the content of $error and empty it with an if statement that detects the warning and then takes it out......it's shocking that a warning ends up going to the error stream, makes no sense.